# ZeroBrane DebugServer Connection Refused

Tags: android, ios, lua, gideros, zerobrane

I've been trying to use the ZeroBrane Debug Server to debug my app, developed using Gideros, while testing in the GiderosAndroidPlayer using the various examples available on the web and those which come in the ZeroBrane samples. Here is what I have done so far...

-Included the mobdebug and socket lua files in my project

-Included a require("mobdebug").start() in main

-Set ZeroBrane interpreter to Gideros

-Started the ZeroBrane Debug Server

-Set the Gideros player in Gideros Studio to the GiderosAndroidPlayer IP address

-Pressed play in Gideros Studio

The code uploads to the device but when it tries to connect to the Debug Server it comes back with a "Connection Refused". I have tried this on both Windows and Mac computers, disabling firewalls, and checking the Debug Server port is open. I have tried specifying localhost and the specific ip address for the debug server in the ZeroBrane settings file and changing the port number.

I think I am now thoroughly stuck and would really appreciate any help you can give as I am now at a point where I need to debug the impact of rotating the device.

Thanks!

Comment: if using localhost try with your IPAddress instead of Localhost

Answer (score 1):

The way remote debugging works requires you to specify address of the computer you device needs to connect to. When you run your application on the device, it makes a call to ZeroBrane Studio to start debugging, but it needs to have IP address of the computer running ZBS for this call to work. You only need to specify this in the `start()` call:

```
require("mobdebug").start('ip.address-of-computer.running.ZBS')
```

When the application is started on the device, you should see it suspended with the current line marker (green arrow) pointing to the next executable line after the `start()` call.

You may also launch your application on the device from ZeroBrane Studio directly; you can find the details in this Gideros [forum post](http://giderosmobile.com/forum/discussion/comment/20903).

Answer (score 0):

instead of localhost or ZeroBrane Server into your IPAddress its work 100%

[image]